# How do I debug a Testcafe browser running in a testcafe/testcafe docker container?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, functional-testing, testcafe

Got a test for a React app's login function in a Page class:

```js
  async login(t) {
    console.log('starting login...');
    debugger;
    this.logBrowserMessages(t);

    await this.loginModal({ visibilityCheck: true });
    await t
      .expect(this.loginModal.visible)
      .ok()
    // then log the user in etc...
```

And the test, which passes when running locally but fails in the container

```js
test.requestHooks(mock)('user can log in', async t => {

  await page.login(t);

  // Make sure test user's orders render.
  await t.expect(page.orders.childNodeCount).gt(1, { timeout: 10000 });
```

The test passes locally but fails (the login doesn't work) when running in the container.

When I run the test locally it debugs as expected:

`testcafe chrome --inspect-brk=9230 ./tests/login.test.js --skip-js-errors`

The process `node_modules/testcafe/lib/cli` shows up in my `chrome://inspect/#devices`, as expected.

However, when I run testcafe in the testcafe docker container it won't debug with any of these commands:

`` docker run --expose 9230 -p 9230:9230 -e BASIC_AUTH_USER -e BASIC_AUTH_PASS -e NODE_ENV=docker -e TEST_USER -e TEST_PASS --shm-size=1gb -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/screenshots/docker:/screenshots testcafe/testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9230  -S -s '/screenshots' --skip-js-errors /tests/**/login.test.js ``

`` docker run --expose 9230 -p 9230:9230 -e \"NODE_PATH=/opt:/opt/testcafe/node_modules:/tests/node_modules\" -e BASIC_AUTH_USER -e BASIC_AUTH_PASS -e NODE_ENV=docker -e TEST_USER -e TEST_PASS --shm-size=1gb -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/screenshots/docker:/screenshots testcafe/testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9230  -S -s '/screenshots' --skip-js-errors /tests/**/login.test.js ``

`` docker run --expose 9230 -p 9230:9230 -e BASIC_AUTH_USER -e BASIC_AUTH_PASS -e NODE_ENV=docker -e TEST_USER -e TEST_PASS --shm-size=1gb -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/screenshots/docker:/screenshots testcafe/testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' --inspect-brk=127.0.0.1:9230  -S -s '/screenshots' --skip-js-errors /tests/**/login.test.js ``

`` docker run --expose 9230 -p 9230:9230 -e \"NODE_PATH=/opt:/opt/testcafe/node_modules:/tests/node_modules\" -e BASIC_AUTH_USER -e BASIC_AUTH_PASS -e NODE_ENV=docker -e TEST_USER -e TEST_PASS --shm-size=1gb -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/screenshots/docker:/screenshots testcafe/testcafe --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9230 --browsers 'chromium --no-sandbox' -S -s '/screenshots' --skip-js-errors  /tests/**/login.test.js ``

`` docker run --expose 9230 -p 9230:9230 -e \"NODE_PATH=/opt:/opt/testcafe/node_modules:/tests/node_modules\" -e BASIC_AUTH_USER -e BASIC_AUTH_PASS -e NODE_ENV=docker -e TEST_USER -e TEST_PASS --shm-size=1gb -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/screenshots/docker:/screenshots testcafe/testcafe  'chromium --no-sandbox' -S -s '/screenshots' --skip-js-errors --inspect-brk=9230 /tests/**/login.test.js ``

Is there some limitation to the container that I'm using that I'm not aware of? I've debugged Node processes running in Docker containers before, I know it can be done. But it was a while ago. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable to enable remote debugging:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 9229:9229 -e NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229" -v /host/path/to/tests:/tests testcafe/testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' /tests/test.js
```

If you don't use `docker-machine`, you can open `http://localhost:9229/json` in your browser and navigate to a DevTools URL specified in the `devtoolsFrontendUrl` property.

Otherwise, use the `docker-machine ip` command to get the IP address of your Docker VM and open `http://${DOCKER_MACHINE_IP}:9229/json` to get a DevTools URL.

Comment: It sounds like testcafe ignores the `--inspect-brk`option when it's running in a docker container, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the Docker image uses an incorrect TestCafe binary that doesn't take V8 flags (including `--inspect-brk`) into account. I've created a bug report about it and will try to fix it in the current development sprint: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3646

Comment: I get an error `Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use` even though it is not in use. I did some research and people said to do `killall -9 node` but it returned `No matching processes were found` . I'm not able to debug. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

On the off-chance you are developing on a Mac, one possibility is that you need to specify the host as `host.docker.internal` rather than `127.0.0.1` in order for the running services on the host to be visible to the container. That could be one of the discrepancies between the local and containerized test runs.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Comment: I think that's to get from the process in the container to the host machine's network. Are you suggesting `--inspect-brk=host.docker.internal:9230`?