# Unable to debug TestCafe browser running in a docker container

Tags: docker, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I have been trying to figure out an issue which only occurs in my TestCafe docker environment but not in local environment. For that I would like to debug TestCafe docker either in inbuilt `chromium` or `firefox`. I followed the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503435/how-do-i-debug-a-testcafe-browser-running-in-a-testcafe-testcafe-docker-containe) but it didn't work for me.

This is the command I use to run my docker container:

```
docker run --net=host -e NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229" -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/reporter:/reporters -w /reporters -e userEmail=admin@test.com -e userPass=password -e urlPort=9000 --env-file=.env testcafe 'firefox' '/tests/uitests/**/concurrentTests/logintest.js' --disable-page-caching -s takeOnFails=true --reporter 'html:result.html',spec,'xunit:res.xml'
```

Running the above with `-p 9229:9229` or without this is what I see:

```
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/66cce714-31f4-45be-aed2-c50411d18319
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

The when I go to the link `ws://0.0.0.0:9229/66cce714-31f4-45be-aed2-c50411d18319` on the Chrome/Firefox browser then nothing happens. Also, `chrome://inspect/#devices` this is empty

**My expectation:**

I would like to see the webpage in the browser so that I know what's happening behind the scene. Also, I would like to see cookies and other API calls being done.

Please suggest how to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, node inspection doesn't work well with the `host` network for some reason. Try to remove the `--net=host` option and add the `-p 127.0.0.1:9229:9229` one. A contained node process should  then appear in DevTools (at `chrome://inspect`) under the 'Remote Target #LOCALHOST' section.

Also, you need to remove the `-e NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229"` option and add the `--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229` flag after `testcafe/testcafe` to avoid the 'Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use' error.

Comment: when I just remove the `--net=host` then I'm able to see the inspect under `chrome://inspect` but it throws error: `Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use`. I can't find any process using port 9229. `killall -9 node` but it returned `No matching processes were found` .

Comment: Also, when I run without `--net=host` and don't debug then I get this error `A request to "https://localhost:9000/" has failed.`

Comment: The process using port 9229 is another node.js process inside of the same container. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ok. So, I don't get the error now that the `Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use` which is great. I still can't access the URL which TestCafe is suppose to test my application on. `A request to "https://localhost:9000/" has failed.` . I guess this is the last hurdle for me. I don't get this error only when I add `--net=host` but then I can't debug. Please suggest

Comment: I think it's some docker network issue which isn't able to access the URL.

Comment: Please ignore my above comment. It was my nginx issue that's why I wasn't able to reach my application's URL. Otherwise you solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the `Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/66cce714-31f4-45be-aed2-c50411d18319` message (or similar), navigate to the `http://localhost:9229/json` URL in your browser and find the devtoolsFrontendURL:

[image]

Copy and paste it to your browser to start your debugging session:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alex Skorkin. I did tried to navigate to `http://localhost:9229/json` URL but I get `The site cannot be reached`. I don't know why I get this. Could it be possible it is because my TestCafe tests are in (`https`) `https://localhost:9000` instead `http://localhost:9000` ? or is there another way to find why I can't reach the URL

Comment: Also, I did use `-e NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect-brk=127.0.0.1:9229"` too but still unable to reach `http://localhost:9229/json`

Comment: ok So I made some progress - When I remove `--net=host` from my command then I'm able to access `http://localhost:9229/json` but I get `Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use`. I can't find any process using port 9229. `killall -9 node` but it returned `No matching processes were found` . Still can't debug :(